# Selenium not scaping product price in a span tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to scrape product prices using Selenium and it doesn't work.
There are no errors or anything. I just run "python main.py" to run the script and the price is not scraping--only the title and the sku is working.

I tried all the variations according to the tutorial and nothing seems to work.

The price is inside a "span"

```
<span class="price">$42.00</span>
```

My script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.kurtadler.com/greenery/wreaths.html')

product_titles = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-item-link')
product_skus = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-item-sku')
product_prices = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.price-box .price')


'''
for product_title in product_titles:
    print(product_title.text)


for product_sku in product_skus:
    print(product_sku.text)
'''
for product_price in product_prices:
    print(product_price)
```

[image]

```
<div class="product-item-info " id="product-item-info_307938" data-container="product-grid" style="">
                                                                
                                <a itemprop="image" href="https://www.kurtadler.com/our-catalog/glutted-santa-with-heart-hands-ornament.html" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">

                                                                                                                                                                <div class="product-item-badge-new">
                                            NEW</div>
                                                                                                                                                    <span style="width:354px;" class="product-image-container">
                            <span style="padding-bottom: 120%;" class="product-image-wrapper">
                                                                <img class="product-image-photo" src="https://www.kurtadler.com/media/catalog/product/k/s/ksa_2024_holiday_5.jpg?width=354&amp;height=425&amp;canvas=354,425&amp;quality=80&amp;bg-color=255,255,255&amp;fit=bounds" max-width="354" max-height="425" alt="Glittered Santa with Heart Hands Ornament"></span>
                        </span>
                                </a>
                                <div itemprop="description" class="product details product-item-details">
                                                                            <strong itemprop="sku" class="product sku product-item-sku">
                                            Item # T3722                                        </strong> <br><strong itemprop="name" class="product name product-item-name">
                                        <a itemprop="url" class="product-item-link" href="https://www.kurtadler.com/our-catalog/glutted-santa-with-heart-hands-ornament.html">
                                            Glittered Santa with Heart Hands Ornament                                        </a>
                                    </strong>

                                    
                                    <div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="307938"><div class="price-box">
        <p class="minimal-price">
        <span class="price-label">Starting at</span>

    <span class="price-container tax weee">
        <span data-price-amount="5.50" data-price-type="" class="price-wrapper "><span class="split">SPLIT</span> <span class="price">$5.50</span> <span class="cur">EA</span>
        <br><span class="case">CASE</span>
                <span class="price">$5.00</span> <span class="cur">EA</span>
            </span>


            </span>

    </p>
    </div>
</div>

                                    
                                                                        <div class="product-item-inner">
                                        <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                                                                            </div>
                                            <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary">
                                                                                                    <div data-bind="scope: 'customer'"><div class="split button wishlist">
        
        <button type="button" data-post="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;https://www.kurtadler.com/wishlist/index/add/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;product&quot;:307938,&quot;uenc&quot;:&quot;aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cua3VydGFkbGVyLmNvbS9vdXItY2F0YWxvZy5odG1s&quot;}}" data-action="add-to-wishlist" class="label action split" fdprocessedid="rvn0m">
            <span>Add to Wish List</span>
        </button>
        <button class="action toggle change" title="Add to:" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-trigger-keypress-button="true" fdprocessedid="0ninze" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span>Add to:</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="items" data-target="dropdown" aria-hidden="true">
            
            <li class="item">
                
                <span role="button" tabindex="0" data-action-keypress="true" data-post="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;https://www.kurtadler.com/wishlist/index/add/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;product&quot;:307938,&quot;uenc&quot;:&quot;aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cua3VydGFkbGVyLmNvbS9vdXItY2F0YWxvZy5odG1s&quot;,&quot;wishlist_id&quot;:&quot;479&quot;}}" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="Wish List">
                            Wish List
                        </span>
                
            </li>
            
            
            <li class="item">
                
                <span role="button" tabindex="0" class="action heightauto new" data-action-keypress="true" data-post-new-wishlist="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;https://www.kurtadler.com/wishlist/index/add/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;product&quot;:307938,&quot;uenc&quot;:&quot;aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cua3VydGFkbGVyLmNvbS9vdXItY2F0YWxvZy5odG1s&quot;}}" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="Create New Wish List">
                            <span>Create New Wish List</span>
                        </span>

                
            </li>
            
            <li class="item">
               <span>
                   <a class="wishlist-link" href="https://www.kurtadler.com/wishlist">View Wish List</a>
               </span>
            </li>
            
            

        </ul>
        
    </div>
    <!-- ko if: customer().firstname -->
        
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<a href="#" class="action tocompare" title="Add to Compare" aria-label="Add to Compare" data-post="{&quot;action&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/www.kurtadler.com\/catalog\/product_compare\/add\/&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;product&quot;:&quot;307938&quot;,&quot;uenc&quot;:&quot;aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cua3VydGFkbGVyLmNvbS9vdXItY2F0YWxvZy5odG1s&quot;}}" role="button">
    <span>Add to Compare</span>
</a>
                                                                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: I don't see the price displayed on the page. Do you see it? It says, you need to login to see the price.

Comment: Yes--I apologize, you do need to sign in. In this case I edited the question with the screenshot of the code of the product item container ~ Thank you

Comment: Can you put the HTML in the text form rather than image?

Comment: Updated! I posted the code of the entire product li

Comment: CSS Selector looks fine to me. I see in the `for` loop that you are printing the price element directly(`print(product_price)`). Try to print it's text like this - `print(product_price.text)`